# Right Float list element in an unordered element

Tags: html, css

I need to float a list of elements to the right. In the below example, I need to float elements SECOND and THIRD to the Right...

```css
#ulelem {
  background-color: green;
}

#ulelem>li {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<ul id="ulelem">
  <li> First</li>
  <li> Second</li>
  <li> Third</li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle:

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rw2Yb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can give them a class name and float them to the right:

```html
<ul id="ulelem">
  <li> First</li>
  <li class="right"> Second</li>
  <li class="right"> Third</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

But you need to switch the Second and Third around, as otherwise, they will be in the wrong order.

Comment: Alternatively, you could float all elements by default, and then remove float (`float: none`) on the first one, either with `:first-child` or using a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can float all elements to the right, and remove the float on the *first child*. [Here's how](http://jsfiddle.net/Rw2Yb/3/):

```css
#ulelem > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}    
#ulelem > li:first-child {
  float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `display:inline-block` with `text-align:right` and then float the first `li` left.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/htcwX/5/)

**CSS**

```css
ul {
 text-align: right;
}
li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding:0 1rem;
}
li:first-child {
 float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hand on how to indent your HTML code, you could use the `text-align` properties: **[DEMO][1]**
HTML

```html
<ul id="ulelem">
  <li> First</li>
  <li> Second</li><li> Third</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
#ulelem {
  background-color: green;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 0.01px/* because IE dislike 0 */
}
#ulelem >li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;/* fallback */
  font-size: 1rem;
}
ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

*The font-size story and vertical-align to pseudo is to avoid on extra-line drawn in the `ul` element.* you may skip it if there's no background or margin/padding alike that matters to you.
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/Rw2Yb/5/